# On dropdown menu option selection show some cells in the table

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create a web page, where are 2 dropdown menus, and a table. For better understanding I would like to create something like [this](http://www.coin-database.com/series/eurozone-commemorative-2-euro-coins-2-euro.html). So the first dropdown menu would display the years, the second the country names. When I select one of the years or one of the country names, in the table should be shown just those coins which were issued in that year or by that country.

I was looking for this question on the Internet, and I have found this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a>
<div id="foo">This is foo</div>
```

I thought, that I will give more "id" to the same  tag in the table to be able to select both dropdown menus and the other cells somehow to hide, but I found out, that I can't add more "id". So now I do not know, how to achive that when I select any of the options, just the selected group of coins would be shown in the table.

Any suggestions, how should I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds to me like you have to have a matrix (table) for each combinaion of country/currency.  But you shouldn't create/hide/show all of the combinations.  If anything, you should just hold them in arrays in memory, and display the proper data on the fly.

Comment: You don't have to use <!-- comments around your scripts anymore, they are dated back to the early days of Netscape (some time in the '90s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use classes instead of IDs. So instead of id="foo" you have class="foo".

The selector would then be(for single element) document.querySelector(".foo").

```
function toggle_visibility(selector) {
   var e = document.querySelector(selector);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

This could easily be expanded to hide/show a group of elements using document.querySelectorAll

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/86c93ao6/

Answer (score 1):

A good way to solve this problem would be to use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to call a PHP script which would query your database, return results and then pass them back to the AJAX call back.

Your jQuery would simply listen for a `.change()` event on your dropdown list and then call the AJAX script.

```
$('your_elem').change(function(){

    // Get the values
    var coin = $('your_elem option:selected').text();
    var country = $('other_elem option:selected').text();

    // Call the AJAX script
    get_new_results(coin, country);
});

// AJAX script which will call the PHP
function get_new_results(coin, country) {

    // Put the values in an array to pass to script
    var json = { 'coin' : coin, 'country' : country };

    // Create a request
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : 'path/to/your/script.php',
        data: { query : json },
        cache: false,

        // Update the table
        success: function(data) {
            // Remove all existing table data
            $('your_table').remove();

            // Your PHP file should echo back the new table, append this to the 
            // the old table container
            $('table_container').append(data);
        }

    });
}
```

This should supply you with a mechanism which will update the table, now we will create the PHP file that will pass back any table data to update your table.

```
<?php

// Variables 
$coin    = $_POST['query']['coin'];
$country = $_POST['query']['country'];

// Do some DB query
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE country = "' . $country . '" AND coin = "' . $coin . '"';

// Use PDO here to get your results 
$res = PDO QUERY FETCH ALL;

// Loop through results;
$rows = "";

foreach($res as $object) {
     $rows += '<tr><td>Specify your formatting</td></tr>';
}

// Echo out the new table to be appeneded, AJAX will capture this
echo '<table>' . $rows . '</table>';
```

Okay, I haven't tested this but I am fairly certain it should provide you a good basis to get started, hope it helps :)

**EDIT:** Instructions on where to put things

In order for AJAX to work, you are going to need to include a reference to jQuery in your header, this is because we are using the jQuery library to build our AJAX call, you can download jQuery at http://jquery.com, alternatively you can use an externally hosted source of the file like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
```

You also need to read up about how to use [PDO in order to reference the database](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_db_odbc.asp), in terms of your application structure you could use something like:

```
- app
--- views
------ your_view.php
------ other_view.php
--- commands 
------ update_table.php     <---- this is the script AJAX calls
- public
--- css
----- your_style.css
----- other_style.css
--- js
----- jQuery.js             <----- jQuery file, if you haven't sourced it externally
----- other_file.js  
----- ajax_commands.js      <----- the AJAX file containing all AJAX scripts
```

This structure implements the MVC framework making allowing you to provide some structure to your application

Comment: thanks, this answer seems very helpful, but unfortunately I don't have any experience with AJAX or PHP, yet. So could you tell me, please, where shoud I paste this code? Should I create a new file and somehow refer to this file, like a CSS file or should I paste this inside my HTML file?